# iOS KMLViewer Sample Polygon Callout?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am pretty new to the iOS world, and since I am a geographer by trade I of course wanted to play with some of the Mapkit functions.

I downloaded the KMLViewer sample, and as part of that sample the KML file has points and polygons.  For the points users can press one of the points and get a call out with the attributes of that point.  This functionally is not built in for the polygons.  I would like to be able to press one of the polygons and have a call out open with its attributes?

Can someone help guide me on how to accomplish this? Thank you so much for any help, guidance, and patients.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

It's all about Overlay view. Use [MKAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to set properties and annotate as much as you like. It's a view so you can build it like any view and put it on the map. You will also find other sample codes [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Also found nice example on OverlayView [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OverlayView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008906-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, looking over the KMLViewer sample, I assume I would add the MKAnnotationView to the KMLParser.m but I'm not sure where and how for KMLpolygons? Again I'm new to iOS coding and any code snippets or direction would be awesome?  Thanks for your time and efforts

Comment: Polygons are nothing but set of points connected together. Aren't they? Points are represented in form of latitude and longitude. You need to take this information, form MKAnnotationView for that point and add it to the map. You are done! I don't know code example for this but it should be same as KMLViewer.